# Problems adding data using onCreateUser() in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to hook into the onCreateUser function with the accounts-password package to add information into another collection when an account is created. I have added this piece of code into the server.js

```
       //server.js
        var ShopDetails = {
        name = "",
        postCode = "",
        type = "";
        openTime = "",
        closeTime = "",
        phoneNum = 0,
        dashboardDetails = false    //until shop populates these fields 
        createdBy = user._id       //_id taken from function below
        }

        Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
        var userId = user._id;
        ShopList.insert(shopDetails);
        return user;
        });
```

The two collections I have in the app are -

- ShopList = new Mongo.Collection("shopList")   //held in a collections folder
- user collection that comes bundled with accounts-password

Once a new user has created an account, I wanted to insert an object with all the required fields (shopDetails) into the ShopList collection (For the purpose of creating a personal dashboard for each shop at a later point) . However after creating a few test accounts, I cannot see them in the ShopList collection in RoboMongo, I know the user accounts are being inserted as I can see them in the user collection. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing server errors?  I would imagine so, as `ShopDetails` is declared outside the context of the `onCreateUser` callback, so `user` will be undefined when you try to get `user._id`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I realised that server.js was not being executed as a JS file causing (a) ShopList not updating with the information (b) Various errors in the server code not showing when the app runs. Thanks richsilv, once up and running I did get that error come up and managed to rectify it. Thanks Ethaan, I wasn’t aware of the optional callback when using the insert, that’s pretty neat. I’ll look into the hooks package later on tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you print

`console.log(shopDetails)` inside the hook?

Also try to use callbacks on the insert as a [second parameter](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert), so we can help you like this

```
ShopList.insert(ShopDetails,function(error,result){
       if(error){
        console.log(error); //should print the error and this help us more to help you =D
      }else{
         console.log(result);
        }
     });
```

also why don you better do something like

```
insertShopDetails = function(userId){
 var ShopDetails = {
        name = "",
        postCode = "",
        type = "";
        openTime = "",
        closeTime = "",
        phoneNum = 0,
        dashboardDetails = false,
        createdBy = userId 
        }
 ShopList.insert(ShopDetails,function(error,result){
   if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }else{
     console.log(result);
    }
 });
}
```

And then just call it inside the `onCreatedHook`

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
        var userId = user._id;
        insertShopDetails(userId);
        return user;
        });
```

The above thing should work, but why dont you better do this using a [hook](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks)?

```
meteor add matb33:collection-hooks


Meteor.users.after.insert(function(userId, doc, modifier) {
    var ShopDetails = {
        name = "",
        postCode = "",
        type = "";
        openTime = "",
        closeTime = "",
        phoneNum = 0,
        dashboardDetails = false 
        createdBy = userId
        }
  ShopList.insert(shopDetails);
});
```